# reshape a csv that has Nan pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a csv 10k row, 26 columns like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b'],
              'col2':[12,2,12,1,13,2.2,14,2.1],
              'col3':[15,1.5,16,1.7,17,1.1,16.5,1],
              'col4':[np.nan,np.nan,17,2,18,2,18,2],})
```

[image]

There are a different number of NaN for each row, some rows have data for all 26 columns, other row do not.

I would like to reshape it to this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a1':[12,15,np.nan,13,17,18],'a2':[2,1.5,np.nan,2.2,1.1,2],
              'b1':[12,16,17,14,16.5,18],'b2':[1,1.7,2,2.1,1,2]})
```

[image]

I would like to the odd instance of `a` or `b` to be `a1`/`b1`, and every even instance to be `a2`/`b2`, and then convert

I think a pivot will work, but cannot get it to work

```
ls=['a1','a2','b1','b2']
df['n']=[ls[i%4] for i in range(df.shape[0])]    
df.iloc[:,1:5].pivot(columns='n')
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with

set seed
then loop through and append rows to original seed
and create final df

```
a1=df.iloc[0,1:4]
a2=df.iloc[1,1:4]
b1=df.iloc[2,1:4]
b2=df.iloc[3,1:4]

for i in range(4,df.shape[0]):
    if i%4==0: a1=a1.append(df.iloc[i,1:4])
    if i%4==1: a2=a2.append(df.iloc[i,1:4])
    if i%4==2: b1=b1.append(df.iloc[i,1:4])
    if i%4==3: b2=b2.append(df.iloc[i,1:4])
pd.DataFrame({'a1':a1,'a2':a2,'b1':b1,'b2':b2}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*As a fully dynamic solution* to a similar dataframe but with more/less rows/columns, one method is to `concat` transposed groups with list comprehension, but in preparation for that you need to:

1. get `n` - the # number of rows per subgroup
2. change index to what will become column names in preparation for .T and concat
3. create groups that get transposed individually

---

```
n = int(pd.Series(df[df['col1'] == df['col1'].shift()].index).diff().max())
df.index = pd.concat([pd.Series(cols)]*len(grp.unique()))
grp = (df.groupby('col1').cumcount() // n)
df_new = pd.concat([df[grp == i].T.iloc[1:] for i in range(grp.nunique())],
                   ignore_index=True)
df_new
Out[1]: 
    a1   b1    a2   b2
0   12    2    12    1
1   15  1.5    16  1.7
2  NaN  NaN    17    2
3   13  2.2    14  2.1
4   17  1.1  16.5    1
5   18    2    18    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest melting the columns, get rid of irrelevant column('variable'), then create a new column that combines `col1` with the modulo of the index (to get either a 0 or 1). The `temp` column generates unique column so that pivoting is possible.

```
(
    df.melt("col1")
    .drop(columns="variable")
    .assign(
        col1=lambda df: df.col1 + (df.index % 2 + 1).astype(str),
        temp=lambda df: df.groupby("col1").cumcount(),
    )
    .pivot("temp", "col1", "value")
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)


     a1     a2       b1     b2
0   12.0    2.0     12.0    1.0
1   13.0    2.2     14.0    2.1
2   15.0    1.5     16.0    1.7
3   17.0    1.1     16.5    1.0
4   NaN     NaN     17.0    2.0
5   18.0    2.0     18.0    2.0
```